# removing an x265 audio track without conversion?

Tags: video, file-formats, conversion

I have an x265 video file with dual audio tracks in different languages. Obviously one is useless to me and I want to remove it without waiting through a lengthy conversion that will lead to quality loss.

I have been using [mkv2mp4](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mkv2mp4/) to do this with x264 in the past, but it spits out an error when I try any x265 coded video. Is there a codec I can install? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html)*, a free command-line tool:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c copy -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 singleaudio.mkv
```

where `0:a:0` is the index of the audio stream you wish to keep. In ffmpeg, numbering starts from zero, so `0:a:0` refers to the first audio stream in the source file. Running `ffprobe input.mkv` beforehand will show the contents of the input.

*download the latest snapshot/nightly build.